# Регулярное выражения для замены в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

к примеру есть строка

```
$string = 'poly "something about" "try again" game caster';
```

### И так вот пара вопросов.

1.Как сделать так что бы функция preg_match() находила все слова и словосочетания в кавычках.
2.Как сделать так что бы другой preg_match() возвращал, все остальное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так что бы функция `preg_match()` находила все слова и словосочетания в кавычках.

для начала определите шаблон регулярного выражения для поиска всего, что в кавычках:

```
$pattern = '/"(.*?)"/';
```

Далее примените его к исходной строке:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

в `$matches` получите искомые подстроки.

> Как сделать так что бы другой preg_match() возвращал, все остальное.

для этого проще использовать другие функции, например, если все другое нужно вернуть в виде строки, то следует просто заменить найденные подстроки на пустые:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern,  "", $string);
```

Если нужен массив, то можно разделить исходную строку по регулярному выражению:

```
$result = preg_split($pattern, $string);
```